# Two guys sit on a bench drinking a beer

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

> Two guys sit on a bench drinking **a beer**.

If what I mean is that they have a beer each, would 'a beer' be okay, or would it sound like they're sharing one?

Comment: You have it correct.  Your sentence means they each have a beer.  If they were sharing one beer you would also say that just as you have.  *Two guys sat on a bench sharing a beer.*  You can also say *Two guys sat on a bench drinking beer.*  This would be the best way to express that they were sharing a six pack of beer (i.e. six cans).

Comment: it doesn't sound like they are sharing one, since that's unusual to do in context, but it is an awkward way to phrase it, and wouldn't be something a native speaker would likely say.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence has 2 meanings:

> They each are drinking their own beer

> They are sharing a beer

It if you want to make it clearer that they are drinking their own beer, you can say

> Two guys sat on a bench drinking beer

Answer (score 0):

You have it correct. Your sentence means they each have their own beer.

Your sentence could be understood to mean that they were sharing a single beer but that situation can be better expressed. If they were sharing one beer that would be clearly expressed just as you have done.

> Two guys sat on a bench *sharing* a beer.

You can also say

> Two guys sat on a bench drinking beer.

This would be the best way to express that they were sharing a six pack of beer (i.e. many cans or bottles).